Disabling USB ethernet
I have a machine attached via USB-c and HD Port to a Dell monitor. This monitor is rather a nice one that allows for some KVM type functionality for machines attached to it. In that vain, it includes ports of other devices like keyboard, mouse, ect; but it also includes a 1Gig ethernet port.
For the other machine that connects to the monitor; I regularly use the monitors USB-C network interface. However, for the Ubuntu box I do not.
Is there any way to disable / regularly down that interface in Ubuntu that would survive a reboot. I know and understand how to do it manually; but was wondering if there is a way to permanently disable it.
Using /etc/netplan to give the machine a static IP which I created manually. I have tried without success the following which does not appear to work:
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    <interface>:
        activation-mode: off

Found at this previous thread
However, that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers,
T

Try Chilli555's answer in the post you linked.  Blacklist the module to keep the kernel from loading it.

I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of:  Permanently disable network interface in Ubuntu 22.04

Great, thank you. Got it.

So, using @Chili555's answer as @eyoung100 had suggested worked.
Thank you.
In my case on an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Test Server running on desktop hardware for testing purposes; I used /etc/modprob.d folder and filled up the blacklist.conf file with all the extra stuff that I really do not need in the server mode.
DON'T FORGET TO:
sudo update-initramfs -u

ref: Stack exchange
That included network card that is part of my Dell KVM monitor.
Lots of Audio / MIDI devices that I use with another PC.
And only left the main screen and the keyboard / mouse.
Even disabling iptables and other useless stuff for my internal testing lab.
T
